# Inheritance from Shape

Tags: c++, sfml

I am creating a button (RectangleShape + Text) and the basic functionality works correctly.

My problem is when I want to use for example 'setOutlineColor', nothing happens.

Should I overwrite all the methods? Or can I indicate that all properties apply to the RectangleShape?

Sorry for my english, this is google translator

```
void Button::setOutlineColor(const sf::Color &color)
{
    // pContainer is RectangleShape
    if (this->pContainer != nullptr) 
        this->pContainer->setOutlineColor(color); 
}
```

Comment: Checking out of curiosity [sfml forum](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php) I see that they in general recommend composition over direct inheritance from `RectangleShape` as I was about to suggest

Answer (score 0):

The outline thickness for shapes is set to 0 by default, so you'll need to give it another value in order to see it.

[See documentation here.](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Shape.php#a5ad336ad74fc1f567fce3b7e44cf87dc)